# How to provide a service returning different mocked response that is called multiple times

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine

I am trying to successfully mock a service call which gets called multiple times in one test, importantly returning different results.

heres an example of code i'm testing:

```
 var myArray = [];
 angular.forEach(docs, function(doc) {
     MyService.execute().then(function(data) {
          myArray.push(data);
     });
 )};
```

and then i provide to my unit tests like so:

```
$provide.service('MyService', function() {
    return {
        execute: jasmine.createSpy('MyService.execute')
    };
});
```

so then the idea is i can provide a mock for my tests like so:

```
it('should do something', function () {

    MyService.execute.and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(mock1);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    // expects my array to have 'mock1' data in
```

so this works for a singular, but when doing more than i assumed just calling it again might work so i tried doing this:

```
it('should do something', function () {

    MyService.execute.and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(mock1);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    MyService.execute.and.callFake(function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(mock2);
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    // expected my array to have 'mock1, mock2' data in
```

but doesn't work as expected it just returns the mock2 twice, can i do an `angular.forEach` in my test for it? i've looked around but cant seem to find anything on how to achieve what i want.

Comment: That mays seem dumb to ask, but are your `mock1` and `mock2` variables different variables ? Otherwise, have you tried with a `tiemout` ?

Comment: @trichetriche yeah they are two different objects, it just only appears to return the last one twice, how would i use the timeout, just wrap both calls in it?

Comment: No, just wrap one in it. Call the first one, wait a second (should be enough to resolve it) and then call the second one.

Comment: @trichetriche seem to have the same issue if i use a timeout, it just uses whichever one is not in the timeout twice

Comment: Can you try putting 4 console logs : 2 before each resolve, showing mock1 and mock2, and 2 after, again showing both variables ?

Comment: Yeah so when i've done that, it's confirmed that it never gets into the mock1 resolve, hence showing 2x mock 2 , it's a shame i can't force like an iterator in it, and just say `if (i === 0) { resolve(mock1) } else { mock2 }`
edit: turns out this does appear to work, though not very nice